# Delete last row and append new information based on criteria in access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have 2 queries that basically do the same calculations. The first goes by monthly basis and the second by quarter. I created a form where a user selects mm-yyyy as a start and end date for their summary outcomes. Usually, the way they select their dates goes by a selected current month and the entire full year before that.

My monthly query is great but for some reason my manager wants me do the following for the quarter query:

If (end-date selected is either Jan, Apr, Jul or Oct) then delete 5th row on the query and replace it with month content from monthly report e.g.
2014Q1,2014Q2,2014Q3,2014Q4 & (01/2015 from monthly query).

If end-date selected is either Feb, May, Aug or Nov then delete 5th row on the query and replace it with month content from monthly report e.g.
2014Q1,2014Q2,2014Q3,2014Q4 & (01/2015 & 02/2015 from monthly query).

If end-date selected is either Mar, Jun, Sep or Dec then keep 5th row on the query e.g. 2014Q1,2014Q2,2014Q3,2014Q4 & 2015Q1.

Could you please tell me how to accomplish that - Thanks.

Comment: Would you mind improving your question to be more readable as well as providing examples of current outputs? It would help to know if the outputs were reports, dumps to Excel sheets, pivots, graphs, etc. Hard to imagine query outputs...especially a single mixed query...column names wouldn't seem to jive

Comment: It sounds like you should write the results to a temp table, then delete unwanted records and add supplemental records. Adjust the report to use the temp table as source.

Comment: Show your query or attempts at coding this.